# Get the height or number of lines of a text label to determine frame height

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How do I get the height or number of lines of a text label in Xamarin Forms? I want this to determine the height of the frame, so that the height of the frame adjusts to the amount of text. I tried to do this with the lenght of the text, but that doesn't work well. So I either need a height number or a number of lines.

I tried the following:

```
int numLines = lbl_test.Text.Split('\n').Length;
```

---

```
int numLines = lbl_test.Text.Length - 
    lbl_test.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty).Length;
```

---

Both didn't work.

Comment: Subscribe to the labels `SizeChanged` event... `lbl_test.SizeChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { //do what you need with the height? Maybe assign this height value to a var? }`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ So now something happens when the size changes? But how do I actually get that size?

Comment: Use `lbl_test.Height` property...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Thank you :)